# Facebook: Social Plugins - do I need access to client's FB profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I'm creating a website for a local business and they also happen to have a Facebook page. I wanted to embed some of their facebook stuff on the business website. Here's an example of some of the things I want to do (see below). But, do I need access to the business's FB profile or can I create this without login information? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is called "like box": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

you only need to create an app, and you can do it under your profile - so no need to ask for business's credentials.